# Оптимизация замены символа в строке на число его повторений

Tags: javascript

Решал задачку на codeWars, чьё условие звучит так:

> Дана строка в качестве аргумента. Если символ в строке встречается впервые, он равен 1. В противном случае, нужно его заменить числом, соответствующим количеству раз встречи с ним в строке.

Например:

```
input   =  "Hello, World!"
result  =  "1112111121311"

input   =  "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
result  =  "123456789101112"
```

Задачу я выполнил следующим кодом:

```js
function numericals(s){
    let emptyArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        emptyArr.push(1);
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
        for (let p = j + 1; p <= s.length; p++) {
            if (s[p] == s[j]) {
                emptyArr[p] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return emptyArr.join("");
}
document.write(numericals("Hello, World"))
```

Тесты код прошёл, всё верно. Только вот возникла ошибка `Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)`, а это значит, что мне нужно как-то оптимизировать мой код. Как это сделать?

Comment: просто вместо вложенного цикла использовать объект

Comment: Я находил подобное решение. Вот: https://repl.it/@EstaP_1987/Code-Wars-Kata-6-Numericals-of-a-String. Но я вовсе не понимаю что значит условие `if (!obj[elem])` из этого же решения

Comment: @DarknessInme, выражение `!obj[elem]` одновременно проверяет и на отсутствие свойства в объекте (так как `!undefined == true`), и на равенство значения свойства нулю (`!0 == true`). Условие срабатывало бы еще и на прочие ложные значения свойства (такие как `NaN`, `null`, `''`, и т.д.), но в коде по ссылке могут быть только два этих случая.

Comment: Спасибо, мне теперь стало понятно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В приведенном коде для хранения количества вхождений используется массив. Для поиска символа в массиве необходимо проверить все элементы, которые уже добавлены.

Вместо массива, для хранения количества вхождений можно использовать объект, в котором ключом будет символ, а значение - количество предыдущих вхождений.

Для поиска нужного значения достаточно проверить наличие ключа в объекте, для этого достаточно получить значение по этому ключу `obj[elem]` и если значение будет `undefined` - значит ключа нет и это первое вхождение, поэтому в результат нужно дописать 1. Если есть - нужно увеличить значение на 1 и дописать в результат.

Например:

```js
function numericals(s) {
  let m = {};
  let result = '';
  for (let j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
    if (m[s[j]] == undefined) {
      m[s[j]] = 1;
    } else {
      m[s[j]] += 1;
    }

    result += m[s[j]];
  }
  return result;
}
document.write(numericals("Hello, World"))
```

Comment: `let m = {};` - ну плохо же ((( Хотя для этой задачи сойдёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy, для большинства задач сойдет :-)

Comment: `m[s[j]] = (m[s[j]] || 0) + 1;`

Comment: Для слов уже не сойдёт, потому что всякие `toString` и `__proto__`

Comment: @Qwertiy, для слов в общем - да, но обычно на них накладывают ограничения :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy почему плохо ? он же в функцию записан, а не глобальный объект ?

Comment: @user354190, потому что в общем случае не стоит использовать объект с непустым прототипом в качестве словаря. Гораздо лучше создать `Object.create(null)`. PS: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1040533/178988

Answer (score 5):

Из-за двух вложенных циклов по строке твой код имеет квадратичную асимптотику. А надо делать с линейной используя словарь. Вот одно из возможных решений:

```js
function f(word) {
  var count = Object.create(null)
  return word.replace(/./g, c => count[c] = ~~count[c] + 1)
}

console.log(f("Hello, World!") === "1112111121311")
console.log(f("aaaaaaaaaaaa") === "123456789101112")
```

Comment: Стоит пояснить, как работает двойной оператор побитового НЕ со всем, что не является `number` ;) это на самом деле малоочевидный, но очень полезный трюк.

Comment: @yar85, как и все битовые операторы, кастит как сможет сначала в число, а потом из double в int32 с превращением NaN в 0.

Comment: Спасибо, но имел в виду - пояснить не мне, а в ответе, для тех кто еще не знает. Этот нюанс ведь имеет непосредственное отношение к предлагаемому решению (его алгоритму).

Comment: Ну когда мне интересно, я комменты тоже читаю. Даже не так, я почти всегда читаю комменты, если собираюсь использовать найденное решение :)

Comment: Да, теперь дублировать эту инфу в ответе уже излишне. А само решение очень красивое.

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант:

```js
function numericals(str) {
  let map = new Map([...str].map(c => [c, 0]));
  let res = '';
  for (let char of str) {
    let cnt = map.get(char);
    map.set(char, ++cnt);
    res += cnt
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(numericals('Hello, World!'))
console.log(numericals('aaaaaaaaaaaa'))
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1040533/178988

Comment: Хороший вопрос, ответы будут весьма познавательны. :)