# Что лучше new Map() или Object.create(null)?

Tags: javascript, объекты, словари

Понятно, что в общем случае `new Map()` гибче, поскольку позволяет различать числовые и строковые ключи, а также использовать ключи любых типов, в том числе ссылочных.

Но что если ключом всегда является строка?

Очевидно, что у объекта куда более компактное обращение к свойствам по свойствам по сравнению с картой - квадратные скобочки, а не вызовы методов, соответственно оказываются применимы операторы в духе `++` и `+=`.

У пустого объекта `{}` есть всякие штуки в прототипе типа `toString` и `__proto__`, что мешает полноценному его использованию в качестве словаря, но `Object.create(null)` этих недостатков вроде бы лишён. По скорости объект со словарём я никогда не сравнивал, хотя, наверное, стоило бы.

В общем, **на какие критерии стоит обратить внимание при выборе между ними** и что скорее всего лучше использовать?

Comment: Подкину немножко инфы для использования в ответах: https://jsperf.com/object-vs-map/4

Comment: @yar85, синтетические тесты такие синтетические :)

Comment: @Grundy, если воспринимать результат только как "быстрее/медленнее/одинаково" (игнорируя числовые показатели, которые и правда зависят от многих факторов), то у меня еще не было случая когда jsperf врал. Может просто мало тестирую.

Comment: @yar85, jsperf не врет, просто скорость может зависеть как от используемого браузера так и от самого кода и его окружения. Иногда и порядок выполнения может поменять результаты

Comment: @yar85, что-то меня смущает, что Map почти пустой.

Comment: @Qwertiy, там в 7 варианте - заполняются объекты

Comment: Смотря для чего лучше. Каждой задаче - свой иструмент.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, так в этом и запрос.