# Посчитать количество каждого символа или слов в строке (короткое решение)

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, какое самое интересное(возможно короткое) решение для подсчета количества каждого символа в строке, а так же слов вы знаете?

Не спрашивайте зачем мне это) Просто личный интерес для развития.

Я смог придумать такую конструкцию

```js
let str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'.split('');
let col = {};
str.forEach(s => col[s] = str.filter(i => i == s).length);
console.log(col);
```

Если же делать split по пробелу, тогда считаются слова

```js
let str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'.split(' ');
let col = {};
str.forEach(s => col[s] = str.filter(i => i == s).length);
console.log(col);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Оптимизация замены символа в строке на число его повторений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040513/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: @Leks, тут задача совсем другая

Comment: @Grundy тогда это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044321/javascript-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5/1044326#1044326

Comment: Т.е вопрос закрыт из-за дубликата плохого и тоже закрытого вопроса? Очень интересно, тот вопрос явно лучше...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для таких заданий лучше всего подходит метод `reduce`
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```js
let str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'.split('').reduce((acc, item)=> ({
  ...acc, [item]: (acc[item]||0)+ 1
}), {})
console.log(str)
```

**UPDATE**

Здесь я использовал `reduce` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

оператор `spred` (`...`) - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Стрелочную функцию https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Спасибо, круто, но это уже сложнее понять, но ведь и задача не в понимании)

Comment: @Vearo дополнил ответ. Привел все конструкции языка которые вам могут быт непонятны

Comment: Благодарю, но я имел ввиду понимание в лице логики, сходу понять что происходит не получится) Но развернутый ответ точно не лишний

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, короче ли, но за один проход

```js
let str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'.split('');
let col = {};
str.forEach(s => col[s] = col[s]+1 || 1);
console.log(col);
```

Comment: Интересно, спасибо